# What is the result of this Symfony controller code assuming a missing YAML file?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, controller

I want help regarding this question in a quiz about symfony basics

assuming we at the path : localhost:8000/mark

what is the result of this code: assuming we don't know what is in the yaml file

```
    public function mark(): Response{
        return  new Response ("hi mark");   
    }
    /** 
        * @Route("/mark“, name=“lea”)
    */

    public function lea(): Response{
        return  new Response ("hi lea");

    }
```

I think that it is kind of impossible to know for sure since we don"t have the yaml file, but if i had to guess i would say it will execute mark() because it is the first method in our controller

Comment: if annotations are enabled then lea() should called

Comment: my understanding of annotations is that it goes to yaml file and look for the route called in name=lea (in this case) and if it isn't there it goes with the first route defined in the yaml

Comment: no, thats wrong. in my routes.yaml is only 1 entry. all other routes come from annotations. you can call `php bin/console debug:router` in your console to watch existing routes

Comment: What a strangely worded question.  There are lots of yaml config files.  Which one are you talking about?  For routing annotations to even be processed there has to be a few lines in routing.yaml to tell it scan the controller directory.  But there are a gazillion other way to configure the router.  Absolutely none of which will automatically call the first action in a controller file.  If you are paying someone to give you this quiz then ask for your money back.